# Event driven programming with weblogic MDB

Tags: events, jms, weblogic, message-driven-bean

I am building an application which acts as an event listener and based on the events received it needs to execute certain steps or work-flow. Is it better to have events posted to a single queue and MDB invoking different business logic components based on event type or to have one queue per event type and the corresponding MDBs invoke different business logic ? 
Our assumption is that a heavy workflow corresponding to a particular event will not affect the performance of other events since they are processed in separate queues.

Answer (score 1):

Jms has a specific type of operation to support this use-case - [message selectors](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html#bncer).

Briefly, the business-logic message type would be set as a property of the message, and you would use a selector to filter them on a per-consumer basis.

The JMS spec assumes that the JMS implementation will perform optimizations to make these operations efficient, so that it should scale very well. This is the sort of tech that banking transactions are built on.